# How to Handle Primary Key in Entity Framework 5 Code First

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In my EF5 code-first models, creation of new records works better if the database sets the primary key. I am using a Guid for primary key and if `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` is set, SQL Server will always create the `uniqueidentifier`.

However, this causes issues when I am trying to initially seed the database. If I set the Guid in my seed method, SQL Server overrides it. If I don't set the Guid, I get a new record every time. What is a recommended solution to seed the database using pre-set Guids and keep `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` set for my normal operations?

Example class model:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public RecordName { get; set; }
public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
```

Example seed method:

```
var record = new Record()
            {
                Id = new Guid("3B80725E-9550-4933-807F-C2FAA0942225"),
                RecordName = "New Record",
                Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Updated = DateTime.UtcNow,
             };
context.Record.AddOrUpdate(record);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AddOrUpdate has an overload that allows you to specify the key

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514(v=vs.103).aspx)

So you need to supply the method with the natural key:

```
context.Record.AddOrUpdate(c => c.RecordName, new Record()
            {
                RecordName = "New Record",
                Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Updated = DateTime.UtcNow,
             })
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know the additional extension method. The natural key works great for updates. Unfortunately with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] I'm assuming there is not a way to override the Guid / Id for new record?

Comment: I doubt it. When I need the inserted ID during seeding I do this:             var organisation = new Organisation { Name = "Demo" };            context.Organisations.AddOrUpdate(o => o.Name, organisation);SeedMembership(organisation.ID);