# What is the proper way to fix data on the database using .net Core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, seeding

We have to add some rows in our current database. My boss tells me to use migrations for it (we have a .net core app, and are using EF core 1.1.1). I am unsure on how to proceed, I had the understanding that migrations were a "database schema modifications" thing, not a "data update" thing. I know also seeds exist, but I think they are "first/original data filling" to be done once in the project, not at any random moment.
So, should I use seedings or should I use migrations? Does migrations for simple data manipulation even exist? Or is there a third, proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the most common approach is to use plain SQL in your `Up` migration - see the docs on [Data Motion / Custom SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#Migrate%20to%20a%20Specific%20Version%20(Including%20Downgrade))

There are similar suggestions on stack overflow already, see 
[Entity Framework - Migrations - Code First - Seeding per Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759724/entity-framework-migrations-code-first-seeding-per-migration) and 
[Best way to incrementally seed data in Entity Framework 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342459/best-way-to-incrementally-seed-data-in-entity-framework-4-3)

When doing an initial seed, you can just override the `Seed` method in your `Configuration.cs` see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3)

Comment: Seed doesn't exist for  EntityFramework Core...

Answer (score 2):

you can create your own Up/Down override and tell it to create or insert as necessary with T-SQL.  It would be a migration that didn't make schema changes.. The down would remove those seeded items though.

```
public partial class InsertMigrationRows10 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up( MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO SOMETHING(xx, xx, xx)", suppressTransaction: false);
    }
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        //reverse what ever you did in UP
       migrationBuilder.Sql("DELETE SOMETHING ...."); 
    }
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for.  and `Update-Database` (PMC) call would be necessary to get it to run. `dotnet ef database update` otherwise from with in the directory of the project.  Of course keep mind I don't know if this is the best solution either.