# C# EF Code First Seeding Data - Keeps Adding (Instead of updating)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a list of type `User` and when I try to seed my db to reflect updates, it is simply adding all the entries again. I will share my code I am executing in my `Seed()` method. I wish to just update the records (but keep the add functionality), if they **already** exist. Any thoughts?

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

users.Add(new User { FirstName = "Dee", LastName = "Reynolds" });
users.Add(new User { FirstName = "Rickety", LastName = "Cricket" });

users.ForEach(b => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(b));
```

Comment: This is not working because `EF` is comparing on some field (probably id) that you are not populating.  You might try `.Attach(b)` if you already know they exist.

Comment: I can not implement another meaning to b with the current structure. Slightly different scenario than provided question

Comment: It is possible I will not know if object exists or not. I wish to edit if so, or add if not.

Comment: This is a question that gets asked a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17719137/150342. Take care..http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

Answer (score 7):

You simply need to specify the key you want to check against when you are adding/updating the record. So for a new User you would do this:

```
context.Users.AddOrUpdate(x => x.UserName, //Or some other field that you know will be consistant
    new User { FirstName = "Dee", LastName = "Reynolds" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your AddOrUpdate method to specify a property to checked and see if the row already exists:

```
users.ForEach(b => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(c => c.LastName, b));
```

For more info: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application