# EF AddOrUpdate Questions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to ignore a value while using [AddOrUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate(v=vs.103).aspx)?

Also, what values does it look for when matching to a value and deciding what to change. I tried reading [this article](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/), but obviously it didn't help.

Let's say I have two objects in db (I realize this isn't real code):

```
Obj1.fieldA == 1, Obj1.fieldB == 2, Obj1.fieldC == 5
Obj1.fieldA == 1, Obj1.fieldB == 3, Obj1.fieldC == 6
```

And then I try to AddOrUpdate an object that matches both:

```
Obj3.fieldA == 1, Obj3.fieldB == 2, Obj3.fieldC == 6
```

How is it going to decide which one to update, if any/both?

Edit based on comments/answers in regard to Id, which I don't specify.

```
var someGroup = new API.Models.Group
                {
                    Name = "Blah"
                    Organization = "Blabedy blah",
                    Description = "Blah blah"
                }

db.Groups.AddOrUpdate(someGroup);
```

The id property is there but automatically generated:

```
// Id
[Key]
public long Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: "Is it possible to ignore a value while using AddOrUpdate?" - I have no idea what this means.  Please explain better.

Comment: If you are asking how to handle primary/natural keys - have a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17719137/150342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is it going to decide which one to update,

It will update the record with the matching primary key.  For example, if the primary key is a compound key consisting of `fieldA` and `fieldB` then it will match the first records and update `fieldC`

Comment: What if we never specify to PK? It's Id and  automatically generated, I think this is the default for EF.

Comment: Then it will update the record with the matching `Id` value.

Comment: See edit please, we don't specify id when using Add or AddOrUpdate

Comment: Then it will insert a new record since it doesn't find one with a matching key.

Comment: Thanks for your time.